# ReplaceAll with serveral variables. get all combinations

Tags: replacement

How can achieve something like this?

```
a * b /. {a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {10, 100}}
```

I want `{10,100,20,200,30,300}` or something like that (I don't care the order, or sublist) to be returned. What is the right syntaxis?

In my real problem, I have a more complex expresion

```
ComputeMean[S0_, r_, s_, T_, NPaths_] := 
 Sum[f[S0 Exp[(r - 1/2 s^2) T  + 
       s Sqrt[T] RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[0, 1]]], {i, 1, 
    NPaths}] /NPaths

ComputePrice[S0_, r_, s_, T_, NPaths_] := 
 Exp[-r T] ComputeMean[s0, r, s, T, NPaths]

ComputePrice[S0,r,s,T,NPaths] /. { S0 -> {values for S0}, r -> {values for r}, ... }
```

Comment: Join @@ Outer[Times, {1, 2, 3}, {10, 100}] is one way to get the *result* you appear to be after. The replace you are doing is correct, but *its* result is invalid - you cant multiply lists with differing dimensions.

Comment: That was just a simple example. In the real problem, I have a complex expresion and 6 variables. I cannot extend your solution to my real problem, I think.

Comment: Of course it can. Nonetheless, a more concrete example?

Comment: @rasher I have updated the question.

Comment: So why do you claim you can't extend it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment, it's not the replace that's the problem, it's that you create an invalid expression as a result. Here's one way to do this kind of thing, many others...

```
eq = a + b^c - 2 d/e;

vars ={a,b,c,d,e};

alist = {1, 2, 3};
blist = {2, 4, 6};
clist = {3, 5, 7};
dlist = {1, 2};
elist = {-1, -2, 2};


eq /. Map[Rule @@@ Transpose[{vars, #}] &, Tuples[{alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist}]];

%//Short

(*

{11,10,8,13,11,7,35,34,32,37<<142>>,7778,7783,7781,7777,279941,279940,279938,279943,279941,279937}

*)
```

The entries in the result correspond to the tuples' order. You can get the replacements corresponding to the result like so:

```
sets = Map[Rule @@@ Transpose[{vars, #}] &, Tuples[{alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist}]];
sets // Short

(*
{{a->1,b->2,c->3,d->1,e->-1},{a->1,b->2,c->3,d->1,e->-2},<<159>>,{a->3,b->6,c->7,d->2,e->2}}
*)
```

And of course, you can arrange/sort/whatever the tuples to prearrange the output order.

The use of Outer, as in comment, is also still a possibility...

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := a + b^c - 2 d/e
Flatten[Outer[f, alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist]]
```

With same result as above...

Comment: I'd restrict `Flatten` in case the result from `f` is a list :) +1.

Comment: @rasher +1 nice to "see" you around...I have been away myself :)

Comment: @Kuba True, but if fn returns list of lists, or.... so kind of up to user.

Comment: @ubpdqn Back at you! Life has vacillated between bouts of research and bouts of leisure. In the latter mode right now...

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
Times @@@ Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {10, 100}}]
```

or

```
Times @@@ Tuples@({a, b} /. {a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {10, 100}})
```

The issue is multiplication not replacement.

For the more general case:

```
f @@@ Tuples[lst]
```

e.g.

[image]

Comment: In my real problem I don't have just a `Times` operation, but a more complex expresion. I have updated the question.